# Firefox devtools not showing request details

Tags: reactjs, firefox, vite, firefox-developer-tools

I have a Vite react app that works just fine on chrome. I wanted to test it on Firefox but when I open the dev tools it registers my requests but doesn't show any data for headers, payload, response, etc, even though i receive a 401 from the server and it shows me even the size of the request. Is these some special setting I have to do in Firefox? I'm very confused. Thank you in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqDZS.png)

I tried making the request on firefox and was expecting to be able o see the payload and headers of the request to see why it's getting a 401 from the server.